# Recyclerview + viewpager, make toolbar collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a recyclerview inside a viewpager. I also have Tabs above that and a toolbar. I'd like to collapse those (or one of those I have to try it out) when I move the recyclerView down. Basically the same as [here](https://youtu.be/x5o2hGMMmIw?t=45m26s). 
I'm having trouble to get this to work.

Here is what I have:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.cedric.testdesign.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <com.signpetitions.cedric.signpetitions.components.MyFab
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside the viewPager I have a fragment with a recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: See if this helps you http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/collapsing-toolbar-with-tabs-android-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to the toolbar :

app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

Then it works. The issue though is that when the statusbar is transparent the text behind the toolbar is visible. So the statusbar has to have a color.